# Can't Access Parent Variable from Child Object

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to figure out why the controller class is unable to access the properties of the parent it extends.

Using $this to retrieve the shipping method outputs nothing. Var_dump says it is an array with a string length of 0.

Using the parent:: returns error "Undefined class constant 'shipinfo'"

Any idea on what I am doing wrong? I thought public/protected variables can be accessed when the parent class is extended?

```
$data = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));  
$link = new OrderLink($data);
$controller = new OrderLinkController();

class OrderLink{

protected $shipinfo = [
'name'      => '',
'address'   => '',
'unit'      => '',
'city'      => '',
'state'     => '',
'country'   => '',
'zip'       => '',
'phone'     => '',
'email'     => '',
'method'    => ''
];

protected $items;

function __construct($postdata)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($postdata);

    $xml = $xml->Order;

    $billinfo = $xml->AddressInfo[1];
    $this->shipinfo['name']     =  strval($billinfo->Name->Full);
    $this->shipinfo['address']  =  strval($billinfo->Address1);
    $this->shipinfo['unit']     =  strval($billinfo->Address2);
    $this->shipinfo['city']     =  strval($billinfo->City);
    $this->shipinfo['state']    =  strval($billinfo->State);
    $this->shipinfo['country']  =  strval($billinfo->Country);
    $this->shipinfo['zip']      =  strval($billinfo->Zip);

  }
}

class OrderLinkController extends OrderLink
{

    function __construct(){

        echo 'Shipping Method: ' . $this->shipinfo['method'];
        echo parent::shipinfo['method'];

        if ($this->shipinfo['method']    == 'Local Pickup'){
            $this->shipinfo['method']    = 'Pickup';

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are overwriting parent class __construct() method in the child class.

Comment: So if I remove the constructor from the child the variables will be accessible?

Comment: @Query - no, you do not need to remove the constructor, please see my answer below, I have added a further note to explain this concept in detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of small problems:

- You need to call the parent constructor, so you should flow the $postdata needed into the parent through the child (or create it within the child constructor)
- You can use $this-> for shipinfo

  ```
  class OrderLinkController extends OrderLink
  {

      function __construct($postdata){

          parent::__construct($postdata);

          echo 'Shipping Method: ' . $this->shipinfo['method'];
          echo $this->shipinfo['method'];

          if ($this->shipinfo['method']    == 'Local Pickup'){
             $this->shipinfo['method']    = 'Pickup';

          }
      }
  }
  ```

**Further note**: You do not need to instantiate both the parent and child, as you did in the first few lines:

```
$link = new OrderLink($data);
$controller = new OrderLinkController();
```

You should only instantiate the child, sending the data through the child's constructor, once the child's constructor has matched the parent's allowing for the data to flow (see the code I provided above for how this works):

```
$controller = new OrderLinkController($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also add to Katie's answer, that beside the problem with the code itself, there is also a problem with classes structure.

Classes you have are typical to web applications, the `OrderLinkController` is a class which is responsible for incoming requests handling - get the input data, validate it and pass in execution to the business logic object, the Model.

In this case the `OrderLink` is the Model and there should be no parent-child relation between it and the controller. They should stay independent, I would start with modifying the code this way:

```
// it may extend some BaseController class, but not the model class
class OrderLinkController 
{

    function run() {
        // get and parse the input data
        $data = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));  
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
        $xml = $xml->Order;
        // validate the data
        if ($xml->method == 'Local Pickup'){
            $xml->method = 'Pickup';
        }
        // pass the data to the model
        $model = new OrderLink($xml);
        // save the data or do something else with it
        $model->save(); 

        echo $model->getShippingInfo();
    }
}


class OrderLink{

    // it is usually better to have explicitly defined fields
    // rather than an array
    protected $name;
    protected $address;
    protected $unit;
    protected $city;
    protected $state;
    protected $country;
    protected $zip;
    protected $phone;
    protected $email;
    protected $items;

    // model gets already parsed data
    function __construct($data)
    {
        $billinfo = $data->AddressInfo[1];
        $this->shipinfo['name']     =  strval($billinfo->Name->Full);
        $this->shipinfo['address']  =  strval($billinfo->Address1);
        $this->shipinfo['unit']     =  strval($billinfo->Address2);
        $this->shipinfo['city']     =  strval($billinfo->City);
        $this->shipinfo['state']    =  strval($billinfo->State);
        $this->shipinfo['country']  =  strval($billinfo->Country);
        $this->shipinfo['zip']      =  strval($billinfo->Zip);
    }

    public function getShippingInfo() {
        return 'Shipping Method: ' . $this->method;
    }
}

// create and run the controller
$controller = new OrderLinkController();
$controller->run();
```